# How to combine using functor with bind and weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I change the code below to use a weak_ptr instead of shared_ptr and keep the ability to specify method name (as done in std::bind)? It appears std::bind does not support weak_ptr due to it requiring to check the weak_ptr.

```
void foo::a()
{
  m_class.do1(
    std::function<void(int)>(
      std::bind(&foo::b, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1)));
}

void foo::b(int i)
{
}
```

Comment: What would the semantics of this hypothetical bindage be?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What we would like is for the functor to be invoked if weak_ptr::lock returns a valid shared_ptr.

Comment: And what would you do if lock() doesn't return a valid shared pointer?

Comment: `do` is a keyword in C++, and cannot be the name of a function.

Comment: If lock does not return a valid shared pointer I would do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use lambda:

```
void foo::a()
{
    std::weak_ptr<foo> w {shared_from_this()};
    auto l = [w](int i) {
        auto ptr = w.lock();
        if (ptr) {
            ptr->b(i);
        }
    };
    m_class.run(l);
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Will do some tests.

Comment: You can make the variable `ptr` local to the if statement.